# Why flex element takes more place than it's text content and how to change it?

Tags: html, css

After breaking long words inside flex item, it's size doesn't shrink regardless of it's content.

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="outer">
    <div class="inner1">Lots of text1 sdfsdfsdfsdftrtrtrtsddf</div>
  <div class="inner2">Lots of text2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
.parent {
  max-width: 300px;
}

div {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.outer {
  display: flex;
}

.inner1 {
  
}
.inner2 {
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rfd0yh3t/21/

Answer (score 0):

This is because div element is a block element and according to [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements)

> A Block-level element occupies the entire horizontal space of its parent element (container), and vertical space equal to the height of its contents, thereby creating a "block".

And you can fix it by using `min-content` on the child container in it, this makes it takes the width of the longest word.`

You can check [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min-content) for more details